# How to get the smallest cardinality multiset that can add up to another set?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-optimization, multisets

Suppose I have set $z = \{ 1, 5, 6, 10, 11, 35, 36 \}$

How can I find the smallest multiset $x$ that can add up to all the components of $z$?

For example, $x = \{1, 5, 5, 30\}$

```
1 => 1

5 => 5

1 + 5 => 6

5 + 5 => 10

1 + 10 => 11

5 + 30 => 35

1 + 5 + 30 => 36
```

This is sort of like a spanning set, except it's a multiset, and all scalars $\lambda_i$ in the span must $\in \{0,1\}$

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $T$ (your $z$) be the given set of target values, and let $C=\{1,\dots,\max(T)\}$ be the values of the potential coins.  For $c\in C$, let nonnegative integer decision variable $x_c$ be the number of copies of coin $c$.  For $c\in C$ and $t \in T$, let nonnegative integer decision variable $y_{c,t}$ be the number of copies of coin $c$ used to represent $t$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{c\in C} x_c$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{c\in C} c y_{c,t} &= t &&\text{for all $t\in T$} \\
y_{c,t} &\le x_c &&\text{for all $c\in C$ and $t\in T$}
\end{align}

For the example data, your solution $x_1=1, x_5=2, x_{30}=1$ is optimal, as is $x_1 = x_4 = x_6 = x_{30} = 1$.  There are 12 optimal solutions.